# C# Dispose de elementos dentro de una función

Tags: c#, buenas-prácticas

Un cuestión que no tengo clara.
Veo este código de ejemplo en

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Veo que no es necesario hacer command.Dispose()

Cuando estás en una función de este tipo, ¿es una buena prácticar hacer el dispose de los elementos (por ejemplo el Command, DataTable, DataSet, etc.) o simplemente dejar que "mueran" al finalizar la función?

Comment: Entonces podríamos decir que  "using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))" se hace más que para liberar el objeto en sí es para liberar los recursos que gestiona como la conexión a la base de datos ¿?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo siempre aconsejo que si un objeto implementa `Dispose`, es bueno usarlo siempre.

Luego, como en todo, hay matices. En el ejemplo que pones, el `Dispose` del `SqlCommand` no es excesivamente necesario, ya que un objeto de ese tipo no ocupa muchos recursos y no es excesivamente necesario deshacerse de el, se puede dejar su gestión al GC sin mayores problemas.

Otra cosa es la conexión `SqlConnection`. En ese caso si es importante deshacerse del objeto una vez utilizado, ya que es una conexión directa a la base de datos y si no la gestionamos bien puede afectar al rendimiento de la misma. Por eso, como ves en el ejemplo, se usa una estructura `using`.

Resumiendo, como regla general, nunca hace daño hacer `Dispose` de los objetos que implementan la interfaz [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), y es bueno acostumbrase a hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si es una buena practica, ya que al salir de las llaves de los `using` el solo gestiona la realización de `dispose` ej;

```
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(conectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"select id_tipo from Construccion where id_cosa like @id_cosa and activado = 1";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id_cosa", "Unidad"));
                        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                id_unidad = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

También te puedo decir que he realizado un programa con `SQLite` (medio grande), empleando un único `using`como muestras en tu pregunta, y no obtuve tampoco grandes problemas.

En respuesta a tu pregunta la opción mas correcta sera como en el ejemplo que te indique.